# Truncating all the tables in a schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to truncate all the tables in a schema using PostgreSQL. It is showing this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "Building" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "TRUNCATE TABLE "Building" CASCADE"
PL/pgSQL function truncate_schema(character varying) line 15 at EXECUTE statement
```

Here is the function I used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_schema(schema IN VARCHAR) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    statements CURSOR FOR
        SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = schema;
BEGIN
    FOR stmt IN statements LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(stmt.table_name) || ' CASCADE';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_schema(_schema character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
    selectrow record;
begin
for selectrow in
select 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(_schema) || '.' ||quote_ident(t.table_name) || ' CASCADE;' as qry 
from (
     SELECT table_name 
     FROM information_schema.tables
     WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = _schema
     )t
loop
execute selectrow.qry;
end loop;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Don't you think there need a semicolon at end of last line..

Comment: thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because you aren't including the name of the schema in your `TRUNCATE` statement, so it's looking for the table in the `public` schema.

Try changing the `TRUNCATE` statement to something like this:

```
EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(stmt.table_schema) || '.' ||
    quote_ident(stmt.table_name) || ' CASCADE';
```

Also, something to keep in mind about `CASCADE` is that it will [`TRUNCATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html) **any table** that has a *foreign-key* relationship to that table, which can include tables outside of that schema.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

You would also need to add `table_schema`  to the query behind `statements` so that it is available within the `EXECUTE` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It is making an another error record "stmt" has no field "table_schema".